# Как скрыть контактную информацию в WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Как скрыть контактную информацию профиля в WordPress для посетителей с xxx в конце или просто скрыть ее?

```
<div class="profile-description lineheight25 margincenter mb10">
    <div class="pt5 pb5 pl10 pr10">
        <span class="border-grey-bottom blockstyle width-100p mb5 fontbold">
            <?php esc_html_e( 'Contacts', 'rehub-theme' ); ?>
        </span>
        <p class="fontitalic font80">
            <?php if ( isset( $store_address ) && !empty( $store_address ) ) { ?>
                <i class="rhicon rhi-map-marker-alt"></i> <?php echo ''.$store_address; ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ( !empty( $store_user->get_phone() ) ) { ?>
                <br />
                <i class="rhicon rhi-mobile"></i>
                <a href="tel:<?php echo esc_html( $store_user->get_phone() ); ?>">
                    <?php echo esc_html( $store_user->get_phone() ); ?>
                </a>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ( $store_user->show_email() == 'yes' ) { ?>
                <br />
                <i class="rhicon rhi-envelope"></i>
                <a href="mailto:<?php echo antispambot( $store_user->get_email() ); ?>">
                    <?php echo antispambot( $store_user->get_email() ); ?> 
                </a>
            <?php } ?>                          
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну так просто не выводи её

Comment: Вопрос надо писать на русском. Или задавать его на английском Stackoverflow. В этот раз вам перевели вопрос, в другой раз - просто закроют.

Comment: Нудно скрыть информацию для не зарегистрированных пользователей.

Comment: Уточните, в каком именно конце у посетителя xxx: в конце имени пользователя, имени, фамилии, или адреса email до домена?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если вам нужно показывать этот блок только для авторизированных пользователей вы можете проверить его через функцию `is_user_logged_in()`

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>

<div class="profile-description lineheight25 margincenter mb10">
    <div class="pt5 pb5 pl10 pr10">
        <span class="border-grey-bottom blockstyle width-100p mb5 fontbold">
            <?php esc_html_e( 'Contacts', 'rehub-theme' ); ?>
        </span>
        <p class="fontitalic font80">
            <?php if ( isset( $store_address ) && !empty( $store_address ) ) { ?>
                <i class="rhicon rhi-map-marker-alt"></i> <?php echo ''.$store_address; ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ( !empty( $store_user->get_phone() ) ) { ?>
                <br />
                <i class="rhicon rhi-mobile"></i>
                <a href="tel:<?php echo esc_html( $store_user->get_phone() ); ?>">
                    <?php echo esc_html( $store_user->get_phone() ); ?>
                </a>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ( $store_user->show_email() == 'yes' ) { ?>
                <br />
                <i class="rhicon rhi-envelope"></i>
                <a href="mailto:<?php echo antispambot( $store_user->get_email() ); ?>">
                    <?php echo antispambot( $store_user->get_email() ); ?> 
                </a>
            <?php } ?>                          
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<?php else : ?>    

    <a href="#"><?php _e( 'Please login or register to see this information' ); ?></a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает. Ещё такой вопрос а как написать текст для не зарегистрированных пользований чтобы они зарегистрировались.

Comment: @Wonderlancer можно добавить блок else  и  в нем вывести сообщение с предложением зарегестрироваться либо авторизироваться

Comment: Можете написать пример со ссылкой на регистрацию, буду вам так признателен.

Comment: я же не знаю какая у вас ссылка для регистрации))

Comment: Я знаю, просто любую ссылку как пример))

Comment: @Wonderlancer изменил код в ответе

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь!

Comment: Ещё один вопрос, а как можно ограничить контент для определенной роли к примеру подписчик и администратор?

Comment: для этого вы можете либо проверить роль пользователя если он авторизирован либо проврерить capability пользователя когда он авторизирован.

Comment: А как это можно сделать?

Comment: Не надо валить всё в кучу. Задайте новый вопрос на Stackoverflow.